# Which diagram is better for common mode noise rejection?

Tags: noise, differential, common-mode

I want to us [this](https://www.crlsensors.com/prodDocs/sa-107ln.pdf) sensor(107LN type) as in the following signal chain with differential-input DAQ board and a STP CAT6 cable as below:

[image]

Above the GND of the power supply is local/near to the DAQ. Someone told me this will be problem for differential inputs.

So I created a new ground on the sensor X (GND) from B (GND) on the sensor.
Now along the transmission to the DAQ, the ground and the signal is twisted together. See below diagram:

[image]

Is the second diagram better for common mode noise rejection? Why?

Comment: none of the above.  until you complete the schematic.  Where is Earth Gnd connected? what is Signal level, impedance and BW?  What noise exists, how long are cables, what is your required SNR, is there any Anti-aliasing signal conditioner ( Nyquist Filter) ?

Comment: What is that to do with anti-aliasing?

Comment: where does Diff Amp go? What environmental noise exists?

Comment: the question is asking about something else.

Comment: 100 dB CMRR Diff Amp does nothing if the lines are unbalanced impedance lines in the presence of high EM fields. especially on 500m of cable. I may look again tomorrow but you need to answer the other questions

Comment: For better noise rejection it's always better to separate signal Gnd and DC ground.

Comment: It's even better to shield with the common mode extracted from the signal, buffered back to drive the shield of long or high impedance signal pairs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second diagram is better because the differential inputs don't share a wire with the power supply feed providing 0 volts to the sensor. That 0 volt feed will take current and, in the simple DC scenario will cause a volt drop that is an unknown value - that DC volt drop adds to the signal measured: -

[image]

X = unknown volt drop.

Your second diagram is better because the unknown volt drop (x) is disregarded by the differential amplifier.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for this! I really cannot find such info even in books. One more small thing, I also have a sensor with two signal outputs. SA-207 https://www.crlsensors.com/prodDocs/sa-307ln.pdf It is exactly the same sensor but two DC outputs/axis. In that case better use a separate signal ground for each signal? (X and Y twisted with their own ground)

Comment: That's the safe route and, if you are using twisted pairs, that is probably also the common-sense route.

Comment: Cat5,6 PHY network CM hybrid transformers use at least 1nF to connect floating signal ground to earth ground to avoid line noise but shunt RF noise. Since user1234 did not answer my questions, this may be better but still sub-optimal.